# Health Care ChatBots

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I have seen many examples of different health care chatbots examples like [HealthTap](https://www.messenger.com/t/109653792416142) , [your.md](https://www.messenger.com/t/YourDotMD)  who help people find a solution to the most common **symptoms through AI**. The real benefit of these chatbots is the ability to provide advice and informations for an healthy life because some groups of people don’t have a good basic knowledge of health.

I want to build a basic model of these kind of chat bot. 
I have worked with [Neural conversational model](http://www.wildml.com/2016/04/deep-learning-for-chatbots-part-1-introduction/) . but these kind of chatbots need pre-defined dataset of **conversation**.

how can I get start with **basic health care chatbot** ??? I know there are many API available out there on internet but it's not good idea use pre built API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you said, you are constrained by the following:

1. No pre-defined dataset of conversation to train a model
2. No use of APIs for pragmatic reasons - presumably to have better control over what goes on under the hood (my guess).

To be honest, you may as well just try putting together an [expert system](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/artificial_intelligence/artificial_intelligence_expert_systems.htm) with a programming language you feel comfortable with.

For what you hope to do in chatbot form, you would basically prompt people for answers to various *yes/no* or *multiple choice* questions.

You could have it ask questions to determine someone's BMI for instance, as well as any other questions you may find relevant to determining someone's health.

Take a look at the quizzes on this site for inspiration: http://counsellingresource.com/quizzes/

---

This isn't as sophisticated as the Neural Conversational Model you mention, but this approach does not require any training data - which from what you say is a major constraint to what you're doing.